# How to sample rows from a dataframe using two categorical variables?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, datatable

I have a data frame with two categorical variables.

```
samples<-c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C")
groups<-c(1,1,2,3,1,1,1,2,2,2)
df<- data.frame(samples,groups)
df
   samples groups
1        A      1
2        A      1
3        A      2
4        A      3
5        B      1
6        B      1
7        B      1
8        C      2
9        C      2
10       C      2
```

The result that I would like to have is for each given group in `groups` to downsample the data frame to a maximum of x rows for a given sample. In the example here X=2.
Is there an easy way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what your trying to achieve? You say 2 max for a given group but group 1 has 4 observations. Do you mean 2 observations for each sample and group?

Answer (score 1):

See if this is what you want:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

x <- 2
df[, index := seq_len(.N), by = .(samples, groups)]

df <- copy(df[index <= x][,index := NULL])

df

   samples groups
1:       A      1
2:       A      1
3:       A      2
4:       A      3
5:       B      1
6:       B      1
7:       C      2
8:       C      2
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted

Comment: Hi, I have recently noticed that your proposed solution does not randomly select x rows fer category but rather selects the first x rows, which is not the desired behavior. Any other solution for this?

Comment: I didn't know you wanted it in a random way. I think you can just sample the datatable before doing the other steps. See if it works for you: `df <- copy(df[sample(nrow(df)),])`